# Smtplib not working with Env Variables and gets AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, smtplib

I've tried using smtplib to send emails using python, but when I hide my username and password with python-dotenv, the email sending doesn't work and I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 43, in <module>
    server.login(sender_email, password)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 721, in login
    initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 638, in auth
    authobject(challenge).encode('ascii'), eol='')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode
```

I know that the problem isn't with my code, as I've tried substituting the email and password with strings, instead of the program accessing the environment variable. I'm using Ubunutu, and also I've tried printing out the env variables, which they do appear as the string it is supposed to be, and not None, so I'm not sure why this error occurs.
Possibly, it might be because of some encoding format of ascii between python strings and env variables? Idk just throwing out some ideas.

```
import smtplib, ssl
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

sender_email = os.getenv("MY_EMAIL")
receiver_email = os.getenv("YOUR_EMAIL")
password = os.getenv("MY_PASSWORD")

message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of those environment variables is not set, hence one or more of `sender_email` and `password` are `None`. That's why `authobject(challenge).encode('ascii')`
raises `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode`.

You claim that you printed the variables and they are not `None`. In that case, make sure you don't override one of these variables with `None` somewhere else in the code (according to the line number in the stacktrace, there are at least 30 lines of code which are missing from your example).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering. I double checked, and indeed I forgot to check my password env variable, which turned out to be the one with None. From my project, I created a local file .env with my py file, and saved my env variables there, but when I deleted a previous env variable "USERNAME" from that local .env file, I could still access it for some reason with my py file. So is this env variable saved elsewhere than that local .env file I created?